# Can you use mvc controllers in an asp.net app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My project is a web application project in asp.net 4.0. I've taken the steps to be able to add razor '.cshtml' pages. Can I also add mvc controllers for those files or for '.aspx' pages somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do that. Refer to following article ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes MVC and WebForms can co-exist.

A good [overview is here](http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/30/asp.net-webforms-and-mvc-in-the-same-project.aspx), though not written for MVC 3 the concepts should be the same.

Comment: this was written in 2007, so not for MVC3 =) So far I think it's going to work with some updates/adjustments

Comment: @Maslow sorry about that. That is what I get for not proof reading my edit :|